# Delete all cookie and redirect to a html page after certain time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
setTimeout(expireAndRedirect(), 200000)
```

It should call the function `expireAndRedirect` after 200 seconds.
It works only if it's on the same page on which the above function has been written. But I want it to work on application label.
Is there any way in JavaScript to run a thread after 200 seconds irrespective of on which page you are?

Comment: do you mean to say irrespective of the last accessed time?

Comment: can't call a function if it doesn't exist in code for that page. Surely your application has some common files?

Answer (score 0):

Use html5 local storage to save state between pages and check it on every page load. For example:

Setup:

```
localStorage.expireAndRedirectAfter = Date.now() + 200000;
setTimeout(function() {
      expireAndRedirect();
      localStorage.expireAndRedirectAfter = null;
}, 200000);
```

Check state on each page loading:

```
if (localStorage.expireAndRedirectAfter) {
    if (localStorage.expireAndRedirectAfter > Date.now()) {
        expireAndRedirect();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            expireAndRedirect();
            localStorage.expireAndRedirectAfter = null;
        }, localStorage.expireAndRedirectAfter - Date.now());
    }
}
```

This solution will work only if all your pages on same domain.

Answer (score 0):

during login set a cookie with current datetime..

next in javascript on every page load check the difference in time and set the expiration accordingly..